# Hexadecimal values inside byte[] after REST API POST response

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, encryption, serialization

I have a REST API that provides Rijndael encryption and decryption for both strings and byte[]'s.

I am sending a memory stream byte[] to an encryption method as follows:

```
public FileResult EncryptFile(IFormFile fileA){;
    List<IFormFile> fileList = new List<IFormFile> { fileA };
    string fileNameSet = "";
    Documents document = new Documents();
    foreach (var file in fileList) {
        if (file != null) {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                file.CopyTo(ms);
                byte[] fileBytes = APIUtilities.EncryptDecryptByteArray(EncryptionUtilities.Sharding.DataKey(), ms.ToArray(), "E");
                var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
                var fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                document.DocumentFilename = fileName + '_' + DateTime.Now;
                document.Extension = fileExt;
                document.ContentType = file.ContentType;
                document.DateUploaded = DateTime.Now;
                document.DataStream = fileBytes;
                fileNameSet += document.DocumentFilename;
            }
        }
    }
    document.DataStream = APIUtilities.EncryptDecryptByteArray(EncryptionUtilities.Sharding.DataKey(), document.DataStream, "D");
    return File(document.DataStream, document.ContentType, document.DocumentFilename + document.Extension);
}
```

I am aware I'm decrypting the byte[] immediately after encrypting it. It's structured for testing purposes.

When encrypting and decrypting files, I send a serialized C# object structured as follows:

```
Crypto.CryptoFile obj = new Crypto.CryptoFile {
      Key = key,
      Type = type,
      Value = ms
}
```

where the Value property is the byte[] to be encrypted/decrypted provided from the memory stream.

I send the object to the API as follows:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler)) {
    try {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURL);
        var requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        var content = new StringContent(requestJson);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        var result = client.PostAsync("api/cryptofile", content).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <Crypto.CryptoFile>(result);
        }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        if (ex.Message.Length > 0) {}
    }
}
```

The API receives the request as follows:

```
public class CryptoFileController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/cryptofile
    public Crypto.CryptoFile Post ([FromBody]Crypto.CryptoFile obj) {
        try {
            if (obj.Type == "E") {
                obj.Value = Encryption.Security.EncryptBytes(obj.Value, obj.Key);
            }
            else if (obj.Type == "D") {
                obj.Value = Encryption.Security.DecryptBytes(obj.Value, obj.Key);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            if (ex.Message.Length > 0) {}
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

The encryption returns a byte[] that is encrypted successfully.

When decrypting, I receive a byte[] that while decrypted, values within the array are in a hexadecimal format rather than the initial ASCII format provided from the memory stream. As a result, I get hex values within the file upon opening it instead of the initial file values. If I take those hex values to an online ASCII converter, I can convert the hex values to the original file values.

Is there any way to receive the initial ASCII values of the byte array after decryption? Not sure what I'm missing on this one. Any help would be much appreciated, as this is an issue not only with text files but other file types as well.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Wanted to show the contents of the file before and after the process completes.

Before: Encrypt this file, Decrypt this file

After: 456e 6372 7970 7420 7468 6973 2066 696c 652c 2044 6563 7279 7074 2074 6869 7320 6669 6c65 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

Taking the contents after decryption and putting them through an Hex to ASCII translator provides the results before encryption, but the file contents appear in Hex.

Comment: string myString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedBytes);

Comment: @TravelingMan that definitely gets my values, however it doesn't allow me to return the File with the appropriate byte[]. The byte array still provides an output within the file as follows: 

456e 6372 7970 7420 7468 6973 2066 696c
652c 2044 6563 7279 7074 2074 6869 7320
6669 6c65 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

The original text in the file was "Encrypt this file, Decrypt this file"

Comment: Your byte array and the string are the exact same information, it is just two seperate ways of displaying the information. It is all just bytes on a disk and it is up to the program interpreting those bytes how they should be displayed. If you want to see those bytes as they would be represented in a text editor then you need to have your program read it like a text editor via a `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedBytes);` call or similar.

Comment: You shouldn't be using ASCII.  It was superseded over 20 years ago.  I really don't understand why anyone still uses ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Thanks Scott Chamberlain in the comments mentioning that the program decides how to interpret and display data from disk, as I was unaware that Sublime displays Hex encoding by default. As a result, edited the sublime settings and checked other text editors to confirm no issue with encryption and API at all, was an issue caused by the editor itself.

Thank you to all other suggestions, help's appreciated as always.